# eslint does not applay rules inside the return of a .tsx

Tags: reactjs, eslint, tsx

I have configured eslint in my react + Typescrint project using the command: `npx eslint --int` and the standard rules.

The rules are applied correctly in my .js files and outside the .tsx return.

```
import './App.css'

function App () {
  const a = 'Hello World'

  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Typing the "Hello World"  in the a variable  formats it immediately, but the className "App" quotes do not. The indentation does not work either

This is my .eslintrc.cjs:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true
  },
  extends: [
    'standard-with-typescript',
    'plugin:react/recommended'
  ],
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['*.ts', '*.tsx'],
      parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
      parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 'latest',
        sourceType: 'module',
        project: './client/tsconfig.json'
      },
      plugins: [
        '@typescript-eslint',
        'react'
      ],
      rules: {
      }
    }
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: './client/tsconfig.json'
  },
  plugins: [
    'react'
  ],
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off'
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why or can tell me what I am missing in the configuration, thank you very much.

Try to include the quotes, indentation ... rules manually.

Comment: Does `const a = 'Hello World'` gets formatted immediately or on save?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you expect to have happen. Are you referring to the double quotes for JSX property names? IIRC double-quotes are the defaults. What indentation are you referring to?

Comment: I use the standard style, with single quotes and 2 spaces as indentation. And these rules do not apply in jsx. If I put a <h1/> tag inside that div with 4 tabs as indent it doesn't show an error or formatting on save.